# performance of dynamic cursors in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, stored-procedures

I would like to know what is the best practice for better performance when you have a select query that can have any combination of a number (20+) of parameters in the where clause that is passed to a stored procedure.

let's say I have a query that should return the list of people and their addresses (maybe more than 1 address per person). The user wants to search by any possible combination of fields from the person/address tables. The search could be on one field or all 20 or anything in between.

The way  I use to handle this is by creating one cursor like this 
(for simplicity I am listing 2 variables only a varchar and an int)

```
create procedure dynasp for (
in in_name varchar(40),
in in_age int 
 ..... rest of parameters here...


declare cursor cs for 
   select .... from person join address.... 
   where
    (in_age = 0 or in_age = person_age) and 
    (in_name is null or rtrim(in_name)='' or in_name = person.name)
    and...
```

I believe since the value of an input variable is constant, the query should not evaluate it on each row or does it?

The other option that I use is using dynamic cursor built from string in the sp. this way it will contain only the fields that are not empty in the where clause, but I believe this means that the sql needs to be constructed and recompiled on every call to the SP.

My question is for best practices which method above is more recommended, and is there any other better way than the 2 methods mentioned above?

Thank you

Comment: Questions should be tagged with the database you are using.  Questions about performance, even more so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of performance basically hinges on one simple thing:  does your table have any indexes that you intend to use to improve the performance of the query?

If indexes aren't an issue, then your approach is fine.  Well, let me add:  assuming a cursor is necessary for the additional processing that you are doing.  If you can just return the result set and do set-based processing, that is superior to using cursors.

If indexes are an issue, then a long complex `where` statement with a bunch of constant expressions might confuse the MySQL compiler.  The documentation on using indexes for `where` clauses is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html).  MySQL definitely removes constant expressions.  However, in a very complex expression, I'm not sure how well this interacts with choosing the right index.  (I am assuming you are using MySQL based on the syntax).

For this latter case, a dynamic cursor would be beneficial, because it would encourage MySQL to choose an execution plan that uses indexes.

So, if you are not using indexing (or partitioning), then your current approach is fine.  If you are, look at the execution plan for your queries.  If they use the appropriate indexes, then your current approach is fine.  If they are not, consider dynamic cursors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the tables you're searching.  If you have 20+ criteria in the where clause, all containing `or` operators, the query optimizer will not be able to choose a good index to use and will likely just scan the entire table(s).  For small tables, this won't matter but for very large tables, it will be slow.

The other alternative, constructing a dynamic query, will occur some overhead in parsing and choosing a query plan, but when executed, the query will likely be more efficient. (Make sure you're protecting against SQL injection vulnerabilities).

So the best practice is to benchmark both and see what's best in your situation.